# Обязательность нормы в языке и не только

Tags: грамотная-речь, общие-вопросы

Я недавно "запустила" вопрос с провокационным названием "Является ли грамотность формой снобизма", который вызвал большой резонанс. Однако сам вопрос был сформулирован, пожалуй, слишком широко и рыхло.

Меня волнует одна его сторона: насколько языковая норма должна быть обязательной для населения? А, может, и шире - почему государство старается насадить некие нормы в области образования, хорошо это или плохо?

На меня большое впечатление произвела [эта статья](http://gidepark.ru/community/702/content/701611). Думаю, с ней нужно познакомиться каждому думающему человеку.

Заранее прошу прощения, что она не совсем по теме форума. Так что прошу здесь ее не обсуждать и не комментировать, а то модераторы удалят тему.

Модераторов же прошу дать этой ссылке немного повисеть на форуме. Тема уж больно важная!

Comment: Комментировать статью не буду, ибо пока не читал, но боюсь, что самое интересное в ней, как и во всем, что вышло из под пера её автора, - это сам автор.

Comment: Разве там указан автор? Я не нашла. Какой-то американец.

Comment: А, парнон. Я было подумал, что это очередной перл от господина Гершаника. Ну тогда погляжу.

Comment: Не-а, я с ним больше "не дружу"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замечание: сайт, на который идёт ссылка [какой-то не очень](http://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/gidepark.ru)... Сама статья какая-то слишком кричащая, политизированная, со спорными утверждениями без ссылок на источники. /∗ Замечание 2: этот ответ тоже со спорными утверждениями и без ссылок на источники. ∗/

Конечно, есть чья-то фраза "Школа шлифует камни, но грубит алмазы", но, думаю, при заданной системе образования результат может отличаться значительно в зависимости от "мелочей"; многое зависит от того какие *лично* учителя.

Мне кажется, что центр, который контролирует язык, нужен. Правильный язык уменьшает количество неоднозначности, обширный словарный запас позволяет общаться на разные темы. Обучая языку (как и другим предметам), детей учат *думать*: анализировать что из чего состоит, как что можно складывать; и даже если какое-то конкретное правило никогда больше не будет в жизни нужно ученику, оно может быть полезно как тренировка мозгов.

Если центральный контроль отменить, то, думаю, сначала будет вроде бы особо незаметно, но в долгосрочной перспективе язык начнёт "распадаться" на расходящиеся друг от друга диалекты.

Для возникновения аналогий и ассоциаций, попробуйте почитать про ситуацию с китайским языком и роль государственного его регулирования.

Comment: Статья, конечно, полемическая, преувеличенная. Но "сказка ложь, да в ней намек". Какие-то верные наблюдения здесь есть.

> Если центральный контроль отменить, то, думаю, сначала будет вроде бы особо незаметно, но в долгосрочной перспективе язык начнёт "распадаться" на расходящиеся друг от друга диалекты.  
Он пока еще и не "сросся". Явственно выделяются по-крайней мере два пласта: литературный язык "культурных" людей и просторечье, которое цветет ипахнет несмотря на все школьное обращование.

Comment: Если массовая общественная система зависит от личности - это плохая система. Впрочем, дело не в этом. Все люди (дети) разные, с разными способностями, обстоятельствами жизни, потребностями и возможностями. Почему же всех "стригут под одну гребенку"? Почему небольшая группа людей решает, чему учить? Как говорить?  
Наверное, это необходимо. Но для меня это - необходимое зло.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, это нормально и правильно, когда государство руководит процессом обучения в стране. Значит, ему, слава Богу, не все равно, а это уже хорошо. Другое дело - в рамках какого политического курса, какой идеологии (если она есть) происходит образование. В Средние века обучение базировалось на богословии, так как во главе государства стояла церковь. Во времена СССР - на социализме и коммунизме (может, старшее поколение подскажет, как предметы в институтах назывались: история КПСС, что там еще?..). Сейчас вроде бы к демократии стремимся. И если при этом акцент в образовании падает на родной язык, то нам еще крупно повезло, и вряд ли можно недооценивать его важность (язык объединяет все сферы деятельности, и единый стандарт правописания все же избавляет от многих проблем и недоразумений). Тем не менее одного языка мало. Недостает в современной системе образования, на мой взгляд, реально полезной информации по экономике. В школе нас учат скорее тому, как быть хорошим наемным работником, чем успешным руководителем или бизнесменом. (Правда, я подразумеваю при этом школу, которую окончила 10 лет назад, может, где-то что-то и меняется, но не думаю, что кардинально. В принципе я более-менее довольна своим школьным образованием, чего, увы, не скажу об институте - вот по ком плачут реформы, так это по высшей школе.) Как выживать в реалиях рынковой экономики - учит жизнь. Интересно вот что: выгодно ли сейчас государству воспитывать экономически грамотных, независимых, умеющих брать на себя ответственность людей? Таких, чтобы постоянно над собой работали в условиях неминуемой конкуренции и не надеялись на льготы и подачки от государства, а сами смогли обеспечить свою семью. Пока не знаю.

Теперь про статью и Америку. Насколько мне известно, среднее образование в США действительно дорого обходится. "Деньги на школы берутся в основном из местных (городских) налогов на недвижимость, так что качество школ сильно зависит от цен на дома и от того, сколько налогов родители готовы платить за хорошие школы." (Википедия) Все-таки у нас (я имею ввиду Россию и Украину, откуда я родом и где живу) финансирование среднего образования уравновешено более-менее, а представьте, если б оно зависело от стоимости Вашего дома. Конечно, тогда жаба задавит, поневоле задумаешься и начнешь права качать: хочу учить своего ребенка тому-то, а тому не хочу. Американцев можно понять. У них огромные налоги (порядка 40 % дохода). Мои родители не платили за мое обучение.

Конечно, надо ко всему относиться критично, формировать свое мнение, и к качеству образования особенно. Создать оптимальную систему обучения - ой как непросто. И как ни стараться всем угодить, всегда кто-то чем-то будет недоволен.

**Дополнение.** Нашла интересную [статью](http://www.snob.ru/selected/entry/52011) о российском образовании в электронной версии журнала со слегка провокационным названием ["Сноб"](http://www.snob.ru/). В ней и о гуманитарном образовании, и о математической школе, и о ЕГЭ. Рекомендую.

Comment: >  У них огромные налоги (порядка 40 % дохода)

Если подумать, то самый низкий в мире подоходный налог в 13% в России - это вершина айсберга. А по факту государство абсолютно спокойно получает ~50-60% зарплаты наемного работника, но т.к. не он лично платит, а работодатель, то никто и не видит разницы...

Comment: Да, "легальные наемники" (официально трудоустроенные работники) скорее всего очень выгодны государству. А вот с бизнесменами может быть все гораздо сложнее.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы попытаться ответить, насколько языковая норма *должна быть* обязательной, надо знать, насколько она обязательна сейчас.

Ну, напишете вы документ с орфографическими ошибками. Хоть для Сбербанка, хоть для полиции, хоть для увольнения с работы. Вас а) никто за это в тюрьму на посадит (и даже не оштрафует), б) вашему документу в любом случае будет дан ход (и результат будет зависеть больше от ясности выражения вашей воли, а не от стиля или опечаток).

Таким образом, сейчас эта норма при малых тиражах носит рекомендательный характер (нет ответственности за нарушение). При увеличении тиража (и то не всегда) появляется какой-то контроль. Например, ошибки в вашем объявлении для газеты будут, скорее всего, исправлены корректором. Но юридической ответственности за "нефактические" опечатки у газеты всё равно нет.

Answer (score -1):

Если языковая норма существует, наверное, она должна быть обязательной для населения. Как и любая норма.

> Почему то всегда выше. чем недоговорные. Потом цены "отпустили", и назвали договорными. 
> Внимательно перечитав собственные мысли некоторых участников форума (по совету DocentI), к сожалению, заметила ошибки.  Например, у Вас, DocentI. После этого ничего не хочется комментировать

Comment: Кажется, спартанцы в подобном случае отвечали "Если".  
Что значит, что норма существует? Даже ученые не всегда знают, что верно, а что нет. Почитайте хотя бы этот форум: сколько здесь вопросов, на которые есть множество ответов, и ни один нельзя признать лучшим.  
Если посмотреть в историческом плане, сама идея нормирования языка возникла не так уж давно. То есть ученые-грамматики существуют веками (например, специалисты по латыни), но это был узкий круг людей, работающих на элиту общества.  
С развитием идей демократии теории стали проецироваться на остальное население без учета его мнения

Comment: Но в школах ведь не заставляют за 11 лет (или сколько там сейчас) идеально выучить родной язык (ведь его надо учить всю жизнь), только самое главное. А литературная норма - это некий идеал, к которому договорились стремиться в обществе. При этом и правильный язык, и народный важны и нужны, так как они зависят друг от друга, подпитывают друг друга.

Comment: Хорошо, если договорились. Боюсь, что большинство просто не спрашивали.   
Помню, в эпоху перестройки у нас были "договорные цены". Почему то всегда выше. чем недоговорные.

Comment: Простите, договорные цены на что Вы имеете ввиду (я еще маленькая тогда была :))?

Comment: Да на все, что угодно. На продукты питания. До этого цены регулировались государством, отчего был дефицит многого необходимого. Потом цены "отпустили", и назвали договорными. В каком-то смысле это действительно "договор", в котором покупатель голосует кошельком. Слово "договорные" я рассматриваю как эвфемизм для "свободные", которые государство не смогло удержать.

Comment: А, Вы про рынковые цены.   
А то, что нас никто не спрашивает, - так и родителей мы себе не выбираем. Тут уж как повезет - в какой стране и в какое время родиться. А чтобы что-то изменить, надо головой об стенку побиться.